# Can we not have two seam components with same name scope in two different projects within a server intance?

Tags: seam

If we have two components with the same name and precedence then seam throws an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two components with the same name and precedence - component name:
```

But these components are in two separate EAR projects.

- Isn't APPLICATION scope confined to one application (EAR)?
- Does it mean the entire instance?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem to have the same components name in diffrent Ear i have done that many times. problem i have had sometime is i accedently dublicated some ejb, or the seam jar in my ear.

Comment: I've done the same before. But when I'm trying to use seam quartz scheduler to run an application component on a cron interval, it seems to force unique component names as this is running as a service within the Jboss instance.